# Camera memory consumption

Tags: android, memory-management, camera

I am taking pictures via the android camera API:

In order to calculate the available memory for some image processing, I want to check whether the image fits into memory.
I am doing this with those functions:

```
   /**
     * Checks if a bitmap with the specified size fits in memory
     * @param bmpwidth Bitmap width
     * @param bmpheight Bitmap height
     * @param bmpdensity Bitmap bpp (use 2 as default)
     * @return true if the bitmap fits in memory false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean checkBitmapFitsInMemory(long bmpwidth,long bmpheight, int bmpdensity ){
        long reqsize=bmpwidth*bmpheight*bmpdensity;
        long allocNativeHeap = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();

        if ((reqsize + allocNativeHeap + Preview.getHeapPad()) >= Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static long getHeapPad(){
        return (long) Math.max(4*1024*1024,Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*0.1);
    }
```

Problem is: I am still getting OutOfMemoryExceptions (not on my phone, but from people who already downloaded my app)

The exception occurs in the last line of following code:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        final byte[] data1 = data;
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inSampleSize = downscalingFactor;
        Log.d(TAG, "before gc");
        printFreeRam();
        System.gc();
        Log.d(TAG, "after gc");
        printFreeRam();
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data1, 0, data1.length, options);
```

downscalingFactor is chosen via the checkBitmapFitsInMemory() method.
I am doing this like that:

```
 for (downscalingFactor = 1; downscalingFactor < 16; downscalingFactor ++) {
    double width = (double) bestPictureSize.width / downscalingFactor;
    double height = (double) bestPictureSize.height / downscalingFactor;
    if(Preview.checkBitmapFitsInMemory((int) width, (int) height, 4*4)){ // 4 channels (RGBA) * 4 layers
        Log.v(TAG, "  supported: " + width+'x'+height);
        break;
    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "  not supported: " + width+'x'+height);
    }
   }
```

Anyone knows why this approach is so buggy?

Comment: `System.gc();` is a nudge... not a guarantee that garbage collection will actually occur.

Comment: http://mobi-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-if-you-want-to-create-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning this :

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data1, 0, data1.length, options);
```

to this :

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(**data**, 0, data.length, options);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are even using this line:    final byte[] data1 = data;

Comment: no- it should be refactored, but that line shouldnt make any difference